# Trying to create a "copy" button for my website, isn't working

Tags: javascript, html, css, clipboard, clipboard.js

`Backstory: I'm making a simple bibliography website and am struggling on the copy button. Even after using clipboardjs, the copy feature of the button isn't working.

I got so desperate to where I asked ChatGPT, and no matter what they suggest, I come up with the same result: it doesn't work! I was hoping someone on this website could help me. I will include my HTML, CSS, and JS below.

```js
'use strict';

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var leftTextbox = document.getElementById('leftTextbox');
    var inputTextArea = document.getElementById('inputTextArea');
    var citationTextArea = document.querySelector('#rightTextbox textarea');
    var copyButton = document.getElementById('copyButton'); // Add copy button reference

    leftTextbox.addEventListener('click', function () {
        this.classList.toggle('active');
    });

    inputTextArea.addEventListener('input', function () {
        this.style.height = 'auto';
        this.style.height = (this.scrollHeight) + 'px';
    });

    inputTextArea.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
        if (event.key === 'Enter' && !event.shiftKey) {
            event.preventDefault();
            citationTextArea.value += this.value + '\n';
            this.value = '';
            this.style.height = 'auto';
            this.style.height = (this.scrollHeight) + 'px';
        }
    });

    var clearButton = document.getElementById('clearButton');

    clearButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
        citationTextArea.value = '';
    });

    // Initialize Clipboard.js
    var clipboard = new ClipboardJS(copyButton, {
        text: function() {
            return citationTextArea.value;
        }
    });

    // Update success and error handling
    clipboard.on('success', function(e) {
        console.log('Text copied to clipboard:', e.text);
    });

    clipboard.on('error', function(e) {
        console.error('Failed to copy text:', e.action);
    });
});
```

```css
/* style.css */

body {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100vh;
}

header {
    background-color: #333;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 20px 0;
    text-align: center;
}

main {
    flex: 1; /* Allow main to take up remaining vertical space */
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: stretch;
    padding: 20px;
}

.textbox {
    width: 45%;
    background-color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    border: 2px solid #ddd; /* Set border width to 2px */
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    transition: border-color 0.3s; /* Add transition effect for border color */
    position: relative; /* Add relative positioning */
}

.textbox.active {
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 2px; /* Increase border width for active state */
}

.textbox h2 {
    margin-top: 0;
}

.textbox-content {
    flex: 1; /* Allow textarea to take up remaining vertical space */
    width: calc(100% - 20px); /* Adjust width for padding */
    height: calc(100vh - 100px); /* Set height to fill remaining viewport height */
    resize: none;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    background-color: transparent; /* Set transparent background color for text area */
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    overflow-y: auto; /* Add scrollbar when necessary */
}

/* Add styles for the clear button container */
.textbox-action-buttons {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin-bottom: 10px; /* Add margin at the bottom */
}

/* Add styles for the clear button */
#clearButton,
#copyButton {
    width: 30px; /* Set width of the button */
    height: 30px; /* Set height of the button */
    border: none;
    background-color: #ccc;
    color: #333;
    font-size: 20px; /* Increase font size for the symbol */
    line-height: 1;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-right: 5px; /* Add some spacing between the buttons */
}

#clearButton:hover,
#copyButton:hover {
    background-color: #999;
    color: #fff;
}

#clearButton {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 5px;
}

#copyButton {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 50px
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Bibby.io</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

<header>
    <h1>Bibby.io</h1>
    <h2>Easy Use MLA Formatting</h2>
</header>

<main>
    <div class="textbox" id="leftTextbox">
        <h2>Input</h2>
        <textarea id="inputTextArea" class="textbox-content" placeholder="Enter text here..."></textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="textbox" id="rightTextbox">
        <h2>Works Cited</h2>
        <div class="textbox-action-buttons">
            <button id="copyButton">&#x2398;</button> <!-- Copy button -->
            <button id="clearButton">&#10006;</button> <!-- Delete button -->
        </div>
        <textarea id="citationTextArea" class="textbox-content" placeholder="" disabled></textarea>
    </div>
</main>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/clipboard.js/2.0.8/clipboard.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js" defer></script> <!-- Include the JavaScript file here with defer attribute -->

</body>
</html>
```

I feel like I tried everything.

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean?

Comment: If you look at your HTML, CSS and JavaScript code above, these codes should work; even the copy button can work too. So, which part doesn't work, you mean?

Comment: [This snippet](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/blob/master/libs/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/copy/src/copy.directive.ts#L18-L30) should work fine

Answer (score 1):

Have you try this way?

```
copyButton.addEventListener(()=> {
    const dataToCopied = citationTextArea.value;
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(dataToCopied )
    .then(() => {
        console.log('Content copied to clipboard!');
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.error('Could not copy content to clipboard: ', err);
    });
})
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Using vanilla JS, I use a function like this:

```
function copyToClipboard(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // Prevent default behavior
    e.stopPropagation(); // Stop from bubbling up so it's only triggered once
    let content = document.getElementById("citationTextArea").value; // Get the content to copy
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(content); // Write the content to the clipboard
}
```

And then would update the copy button in HTML like this:

```
<button id="copyButton" onclick="copyToClipboard(event);return false;">&#x2398;</button>
```

One reason why it might not appear to be working is because of browser security. If you're working on a localhost site, or a site without a valid SSL, there's a good chance your browser is just blocking that feature. It's also pretty finnicky if you're trying to do that within iframes as well.

For example, I got it working here in [this CodePen demo](https://codepen.io/TessaWatkins/pen/GRLpome), but if I were to put it in a snippet here, it wouldn't work because the snippets on this site use iframes to display it.

Comment: Just for clarification: "it doesn't work" means that the button is visible but when i press it it doesn't copy the text. Also, I work on Adobe Brackets.

Comment: Awesome! Feel free to mark this answer as your question's answer so it shows up as answered :)

Answer (score 1):

The code works well. It just needs you to hit the `Enter` button from the keyboard to trigger action move text from `input` field to `Works Cited` field. Then you can use the `copy` button. Because the copy button only copy text from `Works Cited` field.